# RDLC 'export' option showing up behind the data

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, reporting-services, rdlc, rdl

I developed a few rdlc files that I am using in my asp.net/vb.net project.  the reports load great, but when I click 'export' in the toolbar, its showing up behind the data

[image]

I figure I could play around with `Z indexes`, but don't see any method explicitly for the toolbar.  Any thoughts on how to fix?  Below is how my code in the aspx page

```
<asp:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" 
    Font-Size="8pt" InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)" 
    WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" Width="100%" AsyncRendering="true" SizeToReportContent="true">                                                                                                                                             
    <LocalReport ReportPath="Report\myReport.rdlc" EnableHyperlinks="true">                                           
        <DataSources>                                
            <asp:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="SqlDataSource1" Name="DataSet1"/>                                                                  
        </DataSources>                
    </LocalReport>                          
</asp:ReportViewer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case anyone runs into this at a later date, i added the following jquery to my .aspx file and it worked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ctl00_appPages_ReportViewer1_ctl06_ctl04_ctl00_Menu').css('z-index', 99);
    });        
</script>
```